# Unable to sign up for CKAN in order to use API

Tags: authentication

Does anyone know how to sign up for CKAN so that you can work with the APIs? The site only has a 'Log In' option and not a 'Register' one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support question, not a practical programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own CKAN server, activate **create user** authorization setting.

open your ckan.ini file and allow it like this

```
ckan.auth.create_user_via_web = True
```

and you can find api key in the user's profile page.

As you might have guessed, you can't create an account unless the server allows it.